# Apple Appstore submission without storyboard

Tags: app-store, uistoryboard

I just want to confirm that, will Apple App store rejects apps that are not used storyboard but used separate xib file, starting from Feb 2015?

Comment: can any one explain, why I got down vote for this question.

Comment: unless you provide a reference of some kind, this seems like a rumor at best, whether true or not